# Laravel + Vue.js no pasa variables a componente

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Estoy trabajando en éste proyecto con **Laravel** y **Vue.js**. Necesito mostrar una tabla con *mucha* información. Para ello decidí usar un componente Vue que renderice una tabla y los botones de paginación con poca información.

Esto funciona muy bien en la teoría, porque en la práctica las variables que le paso a la instancia del componenete no son obtenidas correctamente (o no lo sé hacer).

Tengo tres partes fundamentales si no me equivoco:

El archivo **app.js** que contiene la instancia principal y la llamada a la API:

```
Vue.component('activities-table', require('./components/ActivitiesTableComponent.vue'));
...
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ...
        activities: [],
        ...
    },
    mounted: function() {
        ...
    },
    created: function() {
        ...
        this.loadActivities();
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        loadActivities: function(page = 1) {
            axios.get('/api/admin/actividades?page=' + page)
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.activities = response.data;
                });
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

Creo que es importante destacar que la llamada a la API se realiza correctamente y que la información devuelta es un archivo JSON, desde el contralador. Éste tiene un método muy simple:

```
public function getActivities(Request $request)
{
    $activities = Activity::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100);

    return $activities;
}
```

Esto devuelve un objeto **LengthAwarePaginator** con la siguiente información:

[image: Datos devueltos por la API]

Que traducida a JSON queda:

[image: Datos devueltos por la API en JSON]

> **Nota:** Esto también se puede constatar en la herramienta de desarrollador de Vue donde `activities` tiene la información correcta.

Dando un gran salto de información, renderizamos la tabla con el elemento `<activities-table :rows="this.activities"></activities-table>` y luego en éste definimos:

```
<template>
    <!-- Actividades -->
    <table id="activities" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
        ...
    </table>
    <!-- /Actividades -->

    <!-- Paginación -->
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pt-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- /Paginación -->
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: [ 'rows' ],
        data: function() {
            return {
                data: this.rows
            }
        },
        created: function() {

        },
        methods: {
            paginate: function(page) {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Cuando hago `console.log(this.rows)` en el ciclo `created` o `mounted` me aparece la siguiente información:

[[image: Dev tools[3]]

¿por qué no funciona esto?

Comment: ¿asumo que el problema es que no está pasando `rows` al componente?

Comment: Parecería que pasar se está pasando porque me aparece en la herramienta de Vue del navegador. Sin embargo, no logro acceder por otro método que por esa herramienta a la información.

Comment: ¿En Vue DevTools sí aparece `rows` definida en el componente? Solo por curiosidad, ¿por qué quieres pasarlos a `data`?

Comment: Exacto, en Vue DevTools aparece perfectamente definida, con toda su información. Quería pasarlo a data porque pensé que era una buena práctica, y además porque no podía acceder a `this.rows`.

Comment: En lo que veo del código aparentemente la variable está bien (salvo lo de data), ¿ya intentaste cambiar el nombre de la variable? que no sea rows, tal vez por descartar que no sea una palabra reservada en algún contexto.

Comment: Sí, ya lo intenté. Lo cómico es que tengo varios componenetes registrados y todos funcionan bien, éste lo estoy comparando línea por línea y incluso cargándole otra información muestra el mismo array-objeto. Lo voy a hacer de cero de nuevo. Jaja.

Comment: Quedo pendiente de la solución, éxitos.

Comment: La solución mientras tanto es pasar directamente el array y NO el objeto al componente. Creo que Vue se comporta de forma extraña cuando se le pasa un objeto como propiedad. Sería: en vez de `:rows="activities"` algo como `:rows="activities.data"`

Answer (score 0):

Te estas complicando demasiado.
Si estas usando vue solo como componente usando las vistas de blade lo que te conviene hacer es:

En la Vista

```
<activities-table :rows="'{{$activities}}'"></activities-table>
```

En el controlador que renderiza la vista

```
return view('nombre_de_la_vista', ['data_vista' => $data, 'activities' => $activities]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la respuesta sugerida por Maru Amallo te sugiero envies la data como json y que vue se encargue de parsearla...

```
<activities-table :rows="{{json_encode($activities)}}"></activities-table>
```